# Excel VBA - Additional search criteria to existing search function

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel UserForm where a user enters a start and end date, and also selects data from 2 comboboxes (ComboBox1 and ComboBox2). The following code searches for rows between those dates, and the rest of the code *(not shown for simplicity)* copies the row to a new sheet.

```
For Each c In rng.Cells
    If (c.value >= startDate And c.value <= endDate) Or _
(c.Offset(0, 2).value >= startDate And c.Offset(0, 2).value <= endDate)
```

I would like to add the ComboBox1.value and ComboBox2.value to the search criteria, and if either of those ComboBoxes are left blank, to ignore that part of the search filter. Any help would be appreciated!

Update:

I am super confused here, and I am still very new to VBA. I still can't seem to figure this out, and would appreciate any help here. Below is my code I tried to hack together, but I don't know if I'm even on the right track.

```
Dim rng As Range, destRow As Long
Dim shtSrc As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet
Dim c As Range '-- this is used to store the single cell in the For Each loop
Dim d As Range '-- this is used to store the single cell in the For Each loop

Set shtSrc = Sheets("Projects") ' Sets "Projects" sheet as source sheet
Set shtDest = Sheets("Look Ahead") 'Sets "Look Ahead" sheet as destination sheet
destRow = 5 'Start copying to this row on destination sheet

' >> Set range to search for dates in Look Ahead period <<
Set rng = Application.Intersect(shtSrc.Range("J:Q"), shtSrc.UsedRange)

' >> Look for matching dates in columns Q and S on Projects Sheet <<

For Each c In rng.Cells
    If (c.value >= startDate And c.value <= endDate) Or _
(c.Offset(0, 2).value >= startDate And c.Offset(0, 2).value <= endDate) Then ' Does date fall between start and end dates? If Yes, then copy to destination sheet

End If
Next
For Each d In rng.Cells
    If (d.value = ComboBox2) Or _
(d.Offset(0, 2).value = ComboBox2) Then
shtSrc.Range("C" & c.Row).Copy shtDest.Range("B" & destRow)
shtSrc.Range("G" & c.Row).Copy shtDest.Range("A" & destRow)      
shtSrc.Range("J" & d.Row).Copy shtDest.Range("E" & destRow)     
shtSrc.Range("Q" & c.Row).Copy shtDest.Range("C" & destRow)      
shtSrc.Range("S" & c.Row).Copy shtDest.Range("D" & destRow) 
destRow = destRow + 1

' > Ends search <
    End If

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make 4 diferent loops for different comboboxes values.
Something like

```
If ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 And ComboBox2.ListIndex = -1 Then 'both combos empty 
    For Each c In Rng.Cells
        If (c.value >= startDate And c.value <= endDate) Or _
        (c.Offset(0, 2).value >= startDate And c.Offset(0, 2).value <= endDate)
      ...
ElseIf ComboBox1.ListIndex <> -1 And ComboBox2.ListIndex = -1 Then  'combo1 not empty 
    Your loop with additional criteria based on combobox1

ElseIf ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 And ComboBox2.ListIndex <> -1 Then  'combo2 not empty 
    Your loop with additional criteria based on combobox2

ElseIf ComboBox1.ListIndex <> -1 And ComboBox2.ListIndex <> -1 Then  'both combos with value 
    Your loop with additional criteria based on combobox1 and combobox2
```

To use `.ListIndex` you'll need to set ComboBox `Style` property to `2 - fmStyleDropDownList`
but this will allow to choose values only from the combobox list.